# LoopDecider Step in Spring Batch Always Runs

Tags: spring-batch

I am facing below issue in one of the Spring Batch Jobs.
Below is the job at high level.

```
<job id="SomeJobId">

      <step id="preValidationStep">
        <tasklet ref="someTaskLetRef"/>
        <next on="COMPLETED" to="actualStepId"/>
        <end on="NO-OP"/>         
      </step>

      <!-- this step runs in a loop -->
      <step id="actualStepId" next="limitDeciderStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" processor="processor" 
            writer="writer" commit-interval="1">
            </chunk>

             <listeners>
                  <listener ref="ItemWriterStepExecutionListener"/>           
             </listeners>
        </tasklet>
      </step>

      <!-- this is limit decider  -->
      <decision id="limitDeciderStep" decider="limitDeciderBean">
            <next on="CONTINUE" to="actualStepId" />
            <end on="COMPLETED" />
      </decision>



</job>
```

**Writer Code is added here :**

```
public class ItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Record>,StepExecutionListener{

private List<Record> records ; // it holds all records to process in afterStep 

public ItemWriter() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void write(List<? extends Record> recepients) throws Exception {

    // this is do nothing method 
    // It just accumulates records and stores in Writer like record.add();

}


@override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

  try{

    // do some processong for all the records accumulated 
    return new ExitStatus("SUCCESS");


  }catch(Exception ex){

        // we want to get exception trace printed here by Spring Batch framework 
        // throwing exception is not helping here . LoopDecider gets called and status is COMPLETED
        //If ExitStatus("FAILED") is used , Job status is FAILED , but  we loose the exception stack trace as no exception is thrown .          
        return new ExitStatus("FAILED"); 
  }


}

@override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution){

    //initliase records 
    records = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

}

As shown in high level code above -

1)**actualStepId** runs in a loop

2)The looping logic is decided by **limitDeciderStep**

The issue is : 
1)Even when **actualStepId** Step throws **ANY EXCEPTION**  (I am throwing from writer ), **limitDeciderStep** is always running

2)Ideally , **limitDeciderStep** should not run and job should stop executing

3)But this is not happening and exception thrown is ignored by Spring Batch and 
  **limitDeciderStep** always runs

4)Job always goes to **Complete state** no matter what exception is thrown . It gets completed only when **LoopDecider** gets the step to completion

Is there any way we can s**top job execution** when exception is thrown and prevent **imitDeciderStep** running ?

**EDIT :**

I removed **LoopDecider** altogether but same behaviour is observed. 
The Job is not getting into **FAILED** state even when exception is thrown from **Writer afterStep** method 
ItemWriterStepExecutionListener is a StepexecutionListener provided in Writer class

The exception is being thrown from **Writer afterStep** since I am doing all final processing in Writer **afterStep**.

Below is pseudo code .

```
 @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {


       try{          
          //do some processing 
       }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new RunTimeException(ex);
       }                 
    }
```

The job doesn't go to failed state because of **throwing exception** from **afterStep** ?

**EDIT 2:** 
After further analysis , I have found below things :

1)I returned Exit Status as **FAILED** from `afterStep` method . After this `LoopDecider` is not called. It was calling earlier since status is not set as **FAILED**

2) But in this case , even when ExitStatus is FAILED, spring batch doesn't show error on the console since we are not throwing any exceptions but returning an ExitStatus.

3)The issue still persists as to how to get job status as FAILED but with Spring Batch log exception message in its context

Comment: That is not supposed to happen. If `actualStepId` fails, the job should fail and subsequent steps should not be executed. Have you tried to remove the decider and see if the job fails as expected when `actualStepId` fails?

Comment: It is correct that after removing LoopDecider also , the same issue is observed. I have edited the question , can you take a look please ?

Comment: Throwing an exception from `ItemWriteListener#afterWrite` should fail the step and the job. Are you sure your writer listener is registered in the step? I don't see any listener in your step config.

Comment: It is not ItemWriteListener#afterWrite but ItemWriteListener#afterStep.

Comment: There is no such `ItemWriteListener#afterStep`. Please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) to help you in the most efficient way.

Comment: The real question here is : Is there any way we can get exit status as FAILED and still get stack trace in Spring Batch

Comment: Yes, this is the default. If a step failed, the job status will be FAILED and you will see the stack trace in the logs. You can always get these two infos from the returned job execution using `JobExecution#getExitStatus` and `JobExecution#getFailureExceptions`.